# Matrix Calculus and Random Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, book-recommendation, machine-learning

After taking a machine learning course, I realised I was lacking fluency in Matrix Calculus and probability calculations involving random vectors. Is there any resource (online or textbook) that has a large set of questions on those two topics and solutions? Actual learning material on those topics would be a bonus, but I primarily need practice.

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic, you might want to give examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: Optimising vector functions wrt to vector components or vectors. And for probability, expectation and conditional probability of functions of random vectors